# Affectionate term for son (or “lad” maybe)

Tags: vocabulaire, orthographe

There is a term I can't find info on.

I know someone from Cameroon who, when he talks to his son, calls him something that sounds like “fils-ton”. I've also heard the same term in a Japanese cartoon (in French obviously) where a man is enthusiastically encouraging a much younger guy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oui, le mot **fiston** existe en effet, c'est un terme d'affection que l'on réserve à quelqu'un pour qui on a une relation de protection, de filiation réelle ou symbolique, ou simplement de camaraderie.

Voir notamment la définition du TLFi [ici](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fiston).

---

English version :

Yes, the word **fiston** exists, you can check its definition at the TLFi [here](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fiston). It's an affectionate term used in relationships where the one using the term has some parenthood, real or symbolic, over the one called *fiston*. Sometimes an experienced worker on the job can say it to young apprentices, or uncles to nephews, and so on.

I guess it's the near exact equivalent of the english *sonny*.